# Rvest with and without curl

Tags: r, curl, rvest

I'm trying to understand internet connections in R little bit better and while there is some information scattered around, I find it hard to follow. Hopefully this question can bring information together. My problem is following. I'm working from my office computer and there is firewall in place. I have tested out how to scrape webpages in R and found out following.

This code works now, because I have deleted `curl` from my package list.

```
library(rvest)

lego_movie <- read_html("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/")

lego_movie %>%
  html_node("strong span") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.numeric()

[1] 7.8
```

But I'm trying to follow https://datascienceplus.com/scraping-javascript-rendered-web-content-using-r/ this example which needs `V8` package (which needs curl). When I install `curl` package following takes place:

```
lego_movie <- read_html("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/")
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : Empty reply from server
```

So there is proxy problem but how do I go around it with `curl` installed as many packages are using it? If I again remove `curl` I can continue with `rvest` only scraping. How `curl` can block my normal `rvest` scraping even if it's not using curl (httr seems to be using curl, but rvest still works)? I find this very confusing.

```
curl installation 3.1
rvest installation 0.3.2
R 3.4.3
```

Comment: use `httr::GET()` vs `xml2::read_html()` and investigate `curl::curl_options("proxy")`. Also, despite seeing it in examples, don't scrape IMDB even for play testing. It's a terms of use violation and it uses [`robots.txt`](https://www.imdb.com/robots.txt) as a technical control.

Comment: will keep in mind IMDB. That seems to be most common example. Thanks for response.

Comment: Just because it's the most common doesn't make it right.